# Why do I have to make a setter for an auto-incremented column in a database?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

In my android app I have created a database using the room persistance library. It contains of a table called `stack` with the columns `stack_id`, `col_1`, `col_2` and `stack_name`. Here's the code for the entity class:

```
@Entity
class Stack(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "stack_name") val stackName: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "col_1") val column1: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "col_2") val column2: String
) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) @ColumnInfo(name = "stack_id") val 
stackId: Int = 0
}
```

Question 1: Is the stack_id correctly implemented? I found this solution to set en auto-incremented column to `0` and it will automaticly auto-increment the value, but it doesn't make sense to me. So, is this correct?

Question 2: Whe I want to build the app, it throws the error:
`Cannot find setter for field. private final int stackId = 0;`
But it would be nonsense to make a setter for an auto-incremented value. So, should I make a setter or is there another solution?

Comment: did you try `@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) @ColumnInfo(name = "stack_id") var stackId: Int`?

Answer (score 2):

You are using concrete class so you need to provide get() and set() for properties.
Use data class which are build for this purpose only .

```
  @Entity
data class Stack(
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) @ColumnInfo(name = "stack_id") val id: Int? = null,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "stack_name") val stackName: String,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "col_1") val column1: String,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "col_2") val column2: String)
```

Comment: But when I create an instance of the class, I have to pass a stack_id then.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move

```
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) @ColumnInfo(name = "stack_id") val 
stackId: Int = 0
```

to the constructor.

```
@Entity
class Stack(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) @ColumnInfo(name = "stack_id") val 
     stackId: Int = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "stack_name") val stackName: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "col_1") val column1: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "col_2") val column2: String
)
```

Why this works? The property is `val`, so is final/immutable, but the assignment in the constructor is a default value which can be overridden by passing in a value.

However in your example the property is in the class body and is assigned the value 0 on init, and cannot be changed as property is immutable.
The second option, as pointed out, is making the property mutable by using `var` instead of `val`.